# CVPR 2022 Text Color

Tags: overleaf

I am trying to change the text color of this template, but I couldn't find how.
Can you please help me with this, and explain where I can change it?
https://de.overleaf.com/latex/templates/cvpr2022-official-latex-template/bphmxkmtqzjh

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, it was on preamble.tex
I expected it to be in a style file.
Anyways, I hope it'd help others to come by this problem.